# Why Covid 19 death record shows ridge and trough?

Tags: covid-19, covid-19-datasets

Here's something I find interesting about Covid 19 death record: The up and down cycle must repeat itself once the horizontal timescale is sufficiently short, regardless of whether the general trend is going upward or downward.

In other words the Covid 19 death record shows "ridge" and "trough".

[image]

This is not a unique phenomena restricted to the US, Brazil also shows a similar trend.

[image]

Why is it so? Any explanation?

Comment: This has been addressed in two other closely related questions.  See https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23719/why-is-the-reported-number-of-covid-19-deaths-lower-on-sundays-and-mondays-in-th and https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/is-the-day-of-week-variance-in-covid-19-case-numbers-a-well-established-phenomen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the footer of the charts: "Each day shows new cases *reported* since the previous day" (emphasis mine).  The virus doesn't care what day of the week it is, but the office staff at the hospital do.  In many hospitals (and coroner's offices, and similar places), the people responsible for reporting on cases and deaths don't work on the weekends, so you get a lull-surge cycle with a period of a week.